# $x^4+5y^4=z^2$ doesn't have an integer solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I hope to show that $x^4+5y^4=z^2$ doesn't have an integer solution.

You may guess that you can solve it using the infinite descent procedure.

I tried it but I had a trouble in solving it.

What I did :

Observe that we can say $(x,y)$=1.

$$-x^4+z^2=5y^4$$

$$-(x^2-z)(x^2+z)=5y^4$$

Set $x^2-z=u$ and $x^2+z=v$.

But since we don't know $(x,z)$, we cannot tell that $(u,v)=1,2$, so failed.

Another :

I observed that

$$k(x^2+ay^2)^2+k(x^2-ay^2)^2=rz^2$$

Then we get $2k=r$, $2ka^2=5r$, $a^2=5$, so failed because $a$ is not an integer.

Comment: But it *does* have an integer solution: $x=y=z=0$. I suspect you want $x,y,z$ to be *positive* integers.

Comment: @ypercube you're right. I correct it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $x=t,y=2t,z=9t^2$ then $x^4+5y^4=81t^4=z^2.$

The parameter $t$ here just serves to remind that if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution so is $(tx,ty,t^2z)$. So one has families of solutions, the generator of the above being $(1,2,9)$. If one were to look for all solutions, finding the generators would be the task.

Update: I searched using maple for $x,y \le 1000$ and found the generator $(1,2,9)$ above along with another generator $(79,36,6881).$ Likely someone who knows more about elliptic curves than I do could show there are only finitely many different families (distinct generators with pairwise gcd 1) and maybe even find all such generators.

Comment: what the...... I spent really much time for solving this...... anyway thanks.

Comment: Nice! It's interesting to know that there are only finite different families. What algorithm can be used to list all of them? How to prove this? How to know whether such equation has finite/infinite/no solution?

Comment: @SiXUlm  I still do not know whether there are only finitely many different families of solutions. I believe the relevant topic is called "elliptic curves" whicfh sometimes can show for Diophantine equations of degree 3 or 4 that there can only be a finite number of such families. Unfortunately I'm not expert enough about this topic to say more for this example.